# c# tcp server client problem

Tags: c#, networking

I wrote a simple C# tcp server/client application, it works fine on the local network but when i tried connecting to the server from a different network, it wont connect.  I looked up on port forwarding and i set the port and ip-address to forward to my local server but still the same problem.  What do i do? What other settings do i need to change?

Answer (score 1):

It rather networking/administrative issue, so it maybe more usefull to ask this question at [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/). But anyway, to figured out what the problem is, you should try to connect to remote server with some another tool like telnet or with something like [online port scanner](http://www.google.com.ua/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=online+port+scanner).

If you can't connect than you should disable all firewalls (or another security tools like "security essentials") and check your router's log files to investigate why you can't connect.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is try to ping the server from the client and the client from the server. This could rule out any issues such as Subnet / VLAN mismatches, which are much lower down the stack than the firewall (although be aware the firewall can block ping packets, though this is not particularly common).

Also, be aware that many ISPs block ports to prevent their customers from hosting services. Perhaps try a different TCP port?